# Сортировка двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

Надо отсортировать массив от меньшего к большему методом пузырька, проблема заключается в том, что я сделал сортировку, но сортируется только в отдельных строках, не могу понять как весь массив отсортировать. Можно какой - то наводящий ответ, или подсказку?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int t[2][5] = {{2, 4, 6, 0, 12}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 14}};
  int change;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
      printf("t[%d][%d] - %d\n", i, j, t[i][j]);

  printf("\n");

  for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
      for(int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
        {
          if (t[i][j] > t[i][j + 1])        
          {
            change = t[i][j];
            t[i][j] = t[i][j + 1];
            t[i][j + 1] = change; 
          }
        }

  for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
      printf("t[%d][%d] - %d\n", i, j, t[i][j]);

  printf("\n");

  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что значит отсортировать двумерный массив. Предположу, что массив должен быть отсортирован при обходе по строкам.
Пронумеруем все элементы массива в порядке сортировки. Из номера n элемента, можно вычислить его "двумерные координаты" в массиве:

```
i = n / numColumns;
j = n % numColumns;
```

Теперь мы можем применить метод пузырька, рассматривая наш двумерный массив как одномерный:

```
int* elem(int** arr, int n, int numColumns) {
    return &(arr[n / numColumns][n % numColumns]);
}

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

...

const int numColumns = 4;
const int numRows = 2;
const int numElements = numColumns * numRows;
for (int pass = 0; pass < numElements - 1; ++pass) {
    for (int n = 0; n < numElements - pass - 1; ++n) {
        if (*elem(t, n, numColumns) > *elem(t, n + 1, numColumns)) {
            swap(elem(t, n, numColumns), elem(t, n + 1, numColumns));
        }
    }
}
```

Код я не компилировал, так что заранее извиняюсь, если где ошибся.