# отсортировать двухмерный массив методом обмена от меньшего к большему c/c++

Tags: c++, c, массивы, сортировка

все исправно работает со знаком "меньше"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как только меняю его, пропадает один элемент.

буду благодарен за помощь!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int a = 7; const int b = 7;
    double arr[a][b];
    double fl, temp;



    for(int i = 0;i != a;i++)
        for(int j=0; j!=b; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 10 + rand() % (999 - 10 + 1) / 10.;
    
    
    do
    {
        fl = 0;
        for (int j = 6; j != -1; j--) {
            for (int i = 6; i != -1; i--) {
                if (arr[i][j - 1] < arr[i][j]) {
                    temp = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1];
                    arr[i][j - 1] = temp;

                    fl = 1;

                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    } while (fl);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            printf("%.02lf ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/219501/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Меняете на что? Какой именно? Я поменял в `if (arr[i][j - 1] < arr[i][j])` на `>`, указанный эффект не наблюдал... Но есть вопрос - **как именно** вы хотите отсортировать массив? Каким он должен быть — отсортированный массив?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то у вас тут неопределенное поведение, связанное с выходом за пределы массива. Когда `j==0`, вы обращаетесь к элементу с отрицательным индексом `arr[i][-1]`.

```
        for (int j = 6; j != -1; j--) // когда j==0
            for (int i = 6; i != -1; i--)
                if (arr[i][j - 1] < arr[i][j])  // здесь получается arr[i][-1]
                {
                    temp = arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1];  // здесь получается arr[i][-1]
                    arr[i][j - 1] = temp;   // здесь получается arr[i][-1]
                    fl = 1;
                }
```

Написанный вами алгоритм нерабочий.
Общая сортировка срабатывает как раз из-за ошибки с выходом за пределы массива и тем, что неопределенное поведение не вызывает краха программы, пока вы не выходите за пределы  общего куска памяти, занимаемого двумерным массивом (который в памяти хранится как одномерный). Потому что сейчас, когда вы оперируете `if (arr[2][-1] < arr[2][0])`, по по факту получается, что вы сравниваете `if (arr[1][6] < arr[2][0])`.
Если вы исправите ошибку с выходом за пределы массива, у вас перестанет работать сортировка.
Ну и да - лишнее значение появляется если случайное число, находящееся в памяти перед первым элементом массива меньше первого элемента массива `arr[0][-1] < arr[0][0]`. А вообще может не число пропасть а программа упасть.
В принципе, чтобы исправить вам нужно убрать выход за границы массива и после вложенных циклов поставить ещё один цикл, который сравнивает и меняет местами если надо последний элемент предыдущей строки с первым элементом следующей строки.

И замечание - вы же задали размеры массива константами `const int a = 7; const int b = 7;` Почему в циклах вы пользуетесь не ими, а `магическими числами`?

```
for (int j = 6; j != -1; j--)
    for (int i = 6; i != -1; i--)

// должно быть    
for (int j = b-1; j != -1; j--)
    for (int i = a-1; i != -1; i--)
```

Второе замечание - зачем массив типа `double`, если вы его заполняете целыми значениями?

Вы написали пузырьковую сортировку. Если вы будете обращаться с двумерным массивом как с одномерным, то пузырьковую сортировку можно оптимизировать - на каждом шаге внешнего цикла внутренний цикл будет делать на одну итерацию меньше, т.к. одно число уже заняло свою позицию и повторно проверять его не нужно.
Чтобы обращаться с двумерным массивом как с одномерным есть два варианта:

- рассматривать ваш двумерный массив `arr[a][b]` как одномерный `arr[a*b]` - но это по стандарту `С++` - неопределенное поведение, хотя оно будет работать корректно пока `С++` обеспечивает обратную совместимость с `C` (приблизительно
  :) )
- рассчитывать индексы двумерного массива `i` и `j` относительно индекса элемента в одномерном массиве